# DisplayPort, high speed data transfer & breadboards

Tags: pcb, prototyping, displayport

I want to experiment with hooking up a laptop display to a desktop computer. From what I've read, in terms of connectivity this should not be too hard - modern laptop displays use eDP (embedded DisplayPort) which is to a large extent compatible with regular DisplayPort. However, the connectivity is a bit different (the panel I'm looking at uses a 40 pin, 0.5 mm pitch connector).

I am very new to electronics and PCBs (I've experimented a little bit with an Arduino and LEDs but that's about it) and am trying to figure out the right approach here. I've found that I can buy breakout boards for both DisplayPort connectors and the 40 pin connector, which makes me think that I might be able to connect those to my breadboard, add some other circuit elements (mainly the backlight power supply) and get going.

Is this feasible or am I being very naive? I've also read that with high-speed components (which I imagine a DP connection might be) breadboards can result in all sorts of electromagnetic interference.

Of course I can just try and see, but any input on whether I'm thinking in the right direction or if other approaches (e.g. a soldered prototyping board?) would be more hopeful would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure, but I believe you need controlled-impedance traces. Breadboards will distort the signal. That said, a lot of times you can get away with distorted signals. If you have nothing to lose then you may as well try it. It would be better to do it without a breadboard though.

Comment: @ChrisStratton for reference, this is what led me in this direction: http://emerythacks.blogspot.com/2013/04/connecting-ipad-retina-lcd-to-pc.html

Comment: I believe eDP does not necessarily have the dual mode standard included (needs referencing, im not too sure) so you might not be able to simply convert it to other standards. Could you specify the panel you are looking at? We might be able to help you more

Comment: @SamvanHerwaarden You can see the nice straight and consistent traces on that person's circuit board. See the comment where he says he tried to make them the same length. I think length matching is more important than getting the impedance right (which is good because length matching is much easier).

Comment: @user253751 that's why I was thinking the breadboard might make my life easier - all my connector cables are the same length!

Comment: @Ananas_hoi I'm looking at this one: https://www.panelook.com/B173QTN01.4_AUO_17.3_LCM_parameter_31906.html

Comment: @jsotola DisplayPort has 20 pins, eDP requires some additional inputs mainly related to the backlight (brightness control, power, that sort of thing), the signal channels seem mostly the same, https://www.vesa.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/DisplayPort-DevCon-Presentation-eDP-Dec-2010-v3.pdf

Comment: Displayport links are at minimum 1.62 gigabits per lane. I would not even bother to try transmitting that through a breadboard.

Comment: A breadboard is not safe for such experiment because connections can be bad.

Comment: @Justme what about if I skip the breadboard, but still manually wire the two breakout boards? Would that seem more worth trying? Perhaps if I twist the wire pairs with differential signaling together? Or does that kind of bandwidth still seem way out of reach? Thanks!